# SplitView in SwiftUI, only works when clicking on first item, second selection never does anything

Tags: swift, swiftui, splitview

I have list view in SwiftUI and it shows a list of journal entries, it works only when I click first entry. When I click second entry, it never works again. It gets stuck on first entry selected. I have checked and those underlying data for list and journal entries are definitely unique and different.

```
import RealmSwift

final class JournalEntry: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = UUID().uuidString
    @Persisted var date: Date
    @Persisted var name: String
    @Persisted var body: String
    @Persisted var bodySummarizedByAI: String?
    @Persisted var responseToBodyByAI: String?
    @Persisted(originProperty: "entries") var journal: LinkingObjects<Journal>
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
            return "id"
        }
    
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    internal init(name: String, date: Date, body: String, bodySummarizedByAI: String? = nil, responseToBodyByAI: String? = nil) {
        super.init()
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
        self.body = body
        self.bodySummarizedByAI = bodySummarizedByAI
        self.responseToBodyByAI = responseToBodyByAI
    }
}

struct JournalListView: View {
    @ObservedResults(JournalEntry.self) var journalEntries
    
    @State private var selectedEntryID: ObjectId?
    @State private var showingAddNewJournalEntry = false
    
    var body: some View {
        List(journalEntries, id: \.id, selection: $selectedEntryID) { entry in
            NavigationLink(destination: JournalEntryView(entryToEdit: entry)) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(entry.name)
                        .font(.system(size: 25))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Text(entry.date.description)
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    Text(entry.body)
                        .truncationMode(.tail)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                }
            }
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        }
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                Button {
                    showingAddNewJournalEntry = true
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddNewJournalEntry, content: {
            JournalEntryView()
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue by improvising some of the missing parts (in particular, the data item `JournalEntry` and the detail view `JournalEntryView`) and by commenting out the parts that weren't relevant (the `.toolbar` and `.sheet` modifiers).

The only thing needed to make it work was to nest it all in a `NavigationStack`, could this be the problem?

Also, since the data is presumably `Identifiable`, you don't need to specify the id explicitly when building the `List`.

This works for me:

*EDIT* revised to use your `JournalSplitView` as the top-level view.

```swift
struct JournalSplitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            JournalListView()
        } detail: {
            Text("Select journal entry")
        }
    }
}

struct JournalEntry: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let date: Date = Date.now
    let body: String = "body"
}

struct JournalEntryView: View {
    let entryToEdit: JournalEntry
    var body: some View {
        Text(entryToEdit.name)
    }
}

struct JournalListView: View {
    let journalEntries: [JournalEntry] = [
        JournalEntry(name: "first"),
        JournalEntry(name: "second"),
        JournalEntry(name: "third")
    ]

    @State private var selectedEntryID: UUID?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(journalEntries, selection: $selectedEntryID) { entry in
                NavigationLink(destination: JournalEntryView(entryToEdit: entry)) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(entry.name)
                            .font(.system(size: 25))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Text(entry.date.description)
                            .font(.system(size: 10))
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        Text(entry.body)
                            .truncationMode(.tail)
                            .lineLimit(3)
                    }
                }
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            }
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
//            .toolbar {
//                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
//                    Button {
//                        showingAddNewJournalEntry = true
//                    } label: {
//                        Image(systemName: "plus")
//                    }
//                }
//            }
//            .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddNewJournalEntry, content: {
//                JournalEntryView()
//            })
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help you to spot the problem then please update your code example to make it *complete*, so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: I appreciate all the work you had to do. This only partially fixes it however. It works now on iPhone, but still doesnt work on iPad for me. Can you please check it on your end too? I updated original source code to include realm objects definitions too.

Comment: The code in this answer works for me as a standalone example on an iPad 10th gen. running iOS 17.0.1. However, your question title mentions SplitView so it would be helpful if you could elaborate on the parent container structure. If you are using ```NavigationSplitView``` then the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview) says you can have a ```NavigationStack``` in a column but "the link must present a data type for which the stack has a corresponding navigationDestination(for:destination:) modifier". So maybe this is the change needed.

Comment: Apologies, I have a hard time really understanding this. My parent looks like thise

`struct JournalSplitView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            JournalListView()
        } detail: {
            Text("Select journal entry")
        }
    }
}` which is master view of the app, there is no overlying structure beyond this. I am not implementing navigationDestination modifier on my list and I am not sure how to really do that. Sorry again

Comment: OK thanks for the extra detail. I used your ```JournalSplitView``` as the top level view for the rest of the code in this answer and it still works for me on iPad (I can pick different entries from the nav menu and the detail view changes). So I suspect that your navigation may actually be working and it is more of a data management issue. I don't know ```RealmKit``` so I'm not able to help there, sorry.

Comment: Hey Benzy, would you be able by any chance to share that project you have built with me? I am looking into this for second day, still cant figure it out

Comment: I edited the answer to use your ```JournalSplitView``` as the top-level view. That's now the full code, there's nothing more to it.